# chunks file urls problem in laravel and vuejs

Tags: vue.js, webpack

i am developing a web application with laravel and vue
i deploy application in this route in host:

```
https://novintech.info/panel
```

anything is true but chunks file have wrong path and refer to:

```
https://novintech.info
```

for example:

```
https://novintech.info/js/home.js //this is chunk file
```

how to refrence this file to:

```
https://novintech.info/panel/js/home.js
```

please help. thanks

Comment: You can set the chunk paths using the `output.chunkFilename` property in webpack's configuration. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputchunkfilename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by adding **output.publicPath** property in webpackconfig

```
mix.webpackConfig({
  output: {
    publicPath: 'https://novintech.info/info/public/',
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you ran the production script, go to the file generated folder public/, open the file app.js in an editor.
Research for js/chunk and replace it by info/public/js/chunk.